# Summary View equivalent for Links on Modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

In earlier versions of SharePoint, including the classic experience in SP Online, you could add a Links list app part to your home page and choose "Summary View". That view would show only the URL field (the actual "link" field) with a nice square.gif, and hide most of the useless header information, very much like this:

- Link 1
- Link 2
- Link 3

Does the modern experience offer something similar? Even if I create a new "Web Part" view to hide the Notes field, I won't get the square.gif unless I really do some customization on each Link list.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce similar behavior in my SPO modern experience, you could try to use a normal List to add a link column and then try the Gallery view.

[image]